# ENV not recognized in bash? from Npm script call

Tags: node.js, bash

So my `.env` file looks as such:

```
ENV=DEV
```

My `check_env.sh` looks as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "$ENV" = "DEV" ]
then
    yarn start:dev
elif [ "$ENV" = "PROD" ]
then
    yarn start:prod
else
    echo "ENV : has not been set yet..."
fi
```

And my npm script call is as such: `"start": "./check_env.sh"`

I get the message: *ENV : has not been set yet...*

How exactly is the ENV not set? **Am I failing epically at something here?**

Comment: What documentation do you have that leads you to believe contents in `.env` will be exported automatically?

Comment: BTW -- `ENV` is actually a special/reserved environment variable name -- if defined, it names a file that will be sourced even by noninteractive shells at startup. You shouldn't be using it for other purposes.

Comment: .env is read by some application-level stuff, the Dotenv package available in ruby and other languages, but is not a Bash default thing. You can probably `source .env` in the Bash script.

Comment: ...more broadly, the namespace of all-caps variable names is permitted to be used by the operating system and shell itself. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph; to be safe, user-defined applications should use lowercase names for their own variables. (And see the list of *explicitly* reserved names on that same specification page -- note that `ENV` is on it).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I wouldn't not assume that `.env` is a file that is meant to be sourced, no matter how similar to a shell script it may *look*. For example, consider this example found at https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv: "new lines are expanded if in double quotes (`MULTILINE="new\nline"` becomes
`{MULTILINE: 'new
line'}`)" (the newline between "new" and "line" is, of course, swallowed in this comment).